# Linux C language pipes, forks and signals

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, signals

I need help with a homework assignment, the thing is I have to create a simulation of a cans assembly line, by using processes, pipes, forks and signals, I can't use another IPC mechanism as mutex or semaphores.

I know how to fork a process and have a child, in this case, I need to create a can and then pass it through the several stations (child processes) one by one, the stations are like melting, painting, packaging, and like these.

Should I use a structure for the can? or the PID of a child process?

The thing is how can I send a can from station A to station B, then from B to C and that, using pipes, I know how to send a message using a pipe from parent to one child, but in this case I need to communicate all the childs (stations)

further, this has to be on a GUI using QT or GTK (I prefer GTK even I don't know it well seems more simple) and the program needs that if I pause the simulation it has to tell me how many cans were packaged, which station has cans on it, and generate a final report, by each 100 cans, they form a package of cans, I need to say how many packages were made.

I had read a lots of guides, saw some videos, try some examples, but I just can't get the idea of how to know in which child am I currently so I can know which station is and know what to do in that station, and I don't know how to pass the can through all the stations one by one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c fork,exec,getpid problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199284/c-fork-exec-getpid-problem)

Comment: Unfortunately your question is too broad to be answered in the StackOverflow format. You'll need to make a start and/or come back with a more specific question on a specific problem that you encounter. Good luck.

Comment: Whoever told you mutexes and semaphores are IPC mechanisms is wrong. They are _synchronization_ mechanisms for processes.

Comment: I'd have each station as a process; each can as string or string-serialisable data, so that you can push them through pipes. Each process should get a can from its input pipe, do something to it, then push the modified can through its output pipe to the next station. Cans don't have to know any PIDs; in fact nothing does. There is nothing different between piping from parent to child, vs. piping from child to another child.

Comment: ok, then just tell me how i can use the same pipe to communicate several child processs, and how can i know in which child am i? (i know that if fork() returns 0 i am in the child, but how can know which one?) and a little class of signals between processes?

Comment: Not same pipe. You have one pipe between station A and B, one pipe between B and C...

Comment: @Amadan so can i use the same pipe variable to communicate all the childs?

Comment: No, each pipe has one input end and one output end. While it is possible for multiple processes to use each end, the result is nothing that you want (multiple senders: listener can't figure out who is speaking. multiple listeners: any message can only be read by a single listener, so any message read by any particular listener will not get read by anyone else.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposal from comments, in pseudocode (turning into C is homework, so I'm not doing that):

```
make P-A pipe
make A-B pipe
make B-C pipe

if fork()
    // process A
    while (read can from P-A pipe)
        do something to can
        write can to A-B pipe
else if fork()
    // process B
    while (read can from A-B pipe)
        do something to can
        write can to B-C pipe
else if fork()
    // process C
    while (read can from B-C pipe)
        do something to can
        write can to final output
else
    // parent
    get can from input/file (or make a new can)
    write can to P-A pipe
```